# Google App Engine Blob Operations [General]

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm very new to App Engine, but familiar with **Java**. I need help understanding the Blobs API of Google App Engine.

I kind of went through the documentation online, but unfortunately did not understand much of it.
I also spent hours searching online for blogs that contain explanation/tutorial/walk-through about blobs on App engine to no avail.

I'm using the Data store API in the same project without troubles.

I need help with the following:

1. How do you upload a text file as a blob?
2. What is a blob key and how does it figure in creation of a blob?
3. Once I have the blob uploaded how do I open it and read it into a String (for modifying)?
4. How do I write the modified string back to the blob? [Not necessary to be append, one write would do]

Thank you!
An explanation or a link to a tutorial would be nice. :)

P.S If it means anything, I'm on eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Follow the example in Blobstore API, on how to [upload file](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Uploading_a_Blob).
2. BlobKey is a long unique identifier (non-easily-guessable) generated by Blobstore when you store a blob into it.
3. Blobs in Blobstore are immutable, so you can not change their content once they are fully saved into blobstore. You must read blob data, modify it, save it as new blob (and potentially delete old blob). See [Files API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore).
4. See 3.

Since you need to update blob data, then if your data size is smaller then 1Mb, you might be better off just storing blob into Datastore Entity. You can use a [property](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Properties_and_Value_Types) of [`Blob`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Blob) or [`Text`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Texthttp://) type.